# How to unite .pug and node file

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm all new to pug (jade).
I've got the following markup which does exactly what I want for the html part:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= "Project BOT"
  body
    h1 My project BOT
    .container
      .row
        - for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
          .item col-md-3 col-sm-12 #content
            .card
              .front
                p.telegram_id
                p.restaurant_name
                p.discount
                p.timestamp
                button
                .back
          - }
```

I've got a nodejs file where I establish connection to a database and just output the DB contents. Looks as follows:

```
// mysql connection credentials
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'dbname'
});

// connect to database
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

connection.query('SELECT * from botrequests',
  function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
});
```

What I wanna do is to output database fields in the for loop I've got in pug. What's the right (or the possible) way to do so?
Loop is gonna look like:

```
- for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
          .item col-md-3 col-sm-12 #content
            .card
              .front
                p.telegram_id results[i].id
                p.restaurant_name results[i].name
                p.discount results[i].discount
                p.timestamp results[i].time
                button
                .back
          - }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the pug view? via express?

Comment: @bendataclear am not. Should I use express server first?

Comment: I use express and find it very easy to use. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @bendataclear thanks!

Comment: If you've not used express before you might need to run through the 'getting started' pages here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html - This will guide you through creating your first express project, it also has a generator to create the basic website structure for you

Comment: @bendataclear works fine after adding app.listen line. However instead of database values I just get the plain text. Means, db is not passed to pug for now?

Comment: In the jade file you can add `- console.log(results)` to see if it's passing the correct object, or add `- console.log(r)` within the loop?

Comment: sorry I missed escaping the values, you need to add `#{ }` around the data fields, updated my answer

Comment: @bendataclear appreciate your help! huge thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple server using express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set("view engine","jade")

app.get('/', function (req, res) {


    // mysql connection credentials
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'host',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'pass',
        database: 'dbname'
    });


    // connect to database
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

        connection.query('SELECT * from botrequests',
          function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            res.render('JadeFileName', { results: results });
        });

    });

});
```

Jade can then loop through items internally:

```
if results && results.length
  each r in results
    .item col-md-3 col-sm-12 #content
      .card
        .front
          p.telegram_id #{r.id}
          p.restaurant_name #{r.name}
          p.discount #{r.discount}
          p.timestamp #{r.time}
          button
          .back
```